# LINQ orderby in subquery

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to do a simple subquery in LINQ to EF

I did something like this:

```
from p in db.SomeTable
let o = db.SomeTableWithDate
            .OrderByDescending(t => t.Date)
            .FirstOrDefault(lt => lt.SomeValue == value)
select new {p, o}
```

Everything compiles and LINQ isn't complaining, but the result is wrong.
The generated SQL is an OUTER APPLY with a TOP 1, but there is no 'ORDER BY'.

I also tried this:

```
from p in db.SomeTable
select new {
    p, 
    o = db.SomeTableWithDate
            .OrderByDescending(t => t.Date)
            .FirstOrDefault(lt => lt.SomeValue == value)
}
```

But I get the same result. (I prefer 'let' because then I can use variables from the previous 'let' query)

So here is my question: **how can i make LINQ do a real subquery with orderby?**

I want to get the latest date from a linked table

**Solution**

The answer from boran solved it. I just had to do a seperate where first.

```
from p in db.SomeTable
let o = db.SomeTableWithDate
            .Where(lt => lt.SomeValue == value)
            .OrderByDescending(t => t.Date)
            .FirstOrDefault()
select new {p, o}
```

Comment: @boran, I think it's a foreign key.

Comment: What is the generated SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 from p in db.SomeTable
 let o = db.SomeTableWithDate.Where(lt => lt.SomeValue == value)
        .OrderByDescending(t => t.Date)
        .FirstOrDefault()
 select new {p, o}
```

Because you order after filtering, this query will probably have better performance too.

Comment: `Take` returns `IEnumerable<T>` even when you call it with `1` as a parameter, so even if it works (I'm not sure about that) the result will be a bit different then expected: `o` will be `IEnumerable<T>` instead of just `T`.

Comment: Thx. Using a seperate where solved the problem (Take was not needed)